# Why my input makes character move too fast?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to make game on Arduino with OLED display and joystick, but when I start the game and try to move character, it moves too fast.

When I tried to make delays, I expected this will work, but it didn't

Code:

```
void loop() {
  if(hp != 0){
    int numberX = analogRead(X_pin);
    int numberY = analogRead(Y_pin);
    int posX = 64; int posY = 40;
    int enemyPosX = random(32, 96); int enemyPosY = random(24, 56);
    myOLED.drawCircle(enemyPosX, enemyPosY, 2, true, true);
    if(hp == 3){
      myOLED.drawImage(Img_HP_3, 0, 16);
    }
    if(hp == 2){
      myOLED.drawImage(Img_HP_2, 0, 16);
    }
    if(hp == 1){
      myOLED.drawImage(Img_HP_1, 0, 16);
    }
    while(numberX > 1000 && posX < 96){
      posX++;
    }
    while(numberX < 100 && posX > 32){
      posX--;
    }
    while(numberY > 1000 && posY < 56){
      posY++;
    }
    while(numberY < 100 && posY > 24){
      posY--;
    }
    if((enemyPosX < posX + 6 && enemyPosX > posX - 6) && (enemyPosY < posY + 6 && enemyPosY > posY - 6)){
      tone(13, 128);
      hp--;
    }
    myOLED.drawCircle(posX, posY, 4, false, true);
    myOLED.drawCircle(posX, posY, 2, true, true);
    delay(100);
    noTone(13);
    myOLED.clrScr();
  } else {
    myOLED.drawImage(Img_HP_0, 0, 16);
  }
  if(digitalRead(SW_pin) == 0){
    hp = 3;
  }
}
```

Comment: What resolution is OLED display?

Comment: What is intended player speed (pixel per frame)? In calculation player new position you use while(...){variable++;} or while(...){variable--;} shouldnt it be if(...){...}?

Comment: If you intend to control speed by `while(numberY < 100 && posY > 24)  posY--;` you're wrong. Use `if` instead of `while` as @stenliis already mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code:

1. First of all, the the amount of times that posX++, posX--, posY++ or posY-- are excecuted. As @stenliis said, you shouldn't use while cause it will keep increasing the X ot Y position of your character as long as the analog is pressed and even if you press the analog just a moment, the arduino will excecute the code inside the while a lot of times due to the speed of the controller.
2. And second, I wouldn't use the delay() function unless it is really necessary because of the [bussy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), it means that the arduino will stop the excecution of the program for the amount of miliseconds that you pass to the function (in wich case any other parts of the program will stop as well, for example the code that controls your enemies, cause the program stops in the position where the delay() was called).

With this two thing in mind, I think you could use a diferent aproach to "slow down" your character.
Here is an example using "if" in place of "while" and a way round to avoid the bussy waiting (It is not the most elegant way of doing it, I know, but I think it is much easier to understand it this way. Instead, you could use the [millis()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) function)

```
 //this is a global variable, and an example so change the number as you wish
int movementCounter = 150;
void loop() {
  if(hp != 0){
    int numberX = analogRead(X_pin);
    int numberY = analogRead(Y_pin);
    int posX = 64; int posY = 40;
    int enemyPosX = random(32, 96); int enemyPosY = random(24, 56);
    myOLED.drawCircle(enemyPosX, enemyPosY, 2, true, true);
    if(hp == 3){
      myOLED.drawImage(Img_HP_3, 0, 16);
    }
    if(hp == 2){
      myOLED.drawImage(Img_HP_2, 0, 16);
    }
    if(hp == 1){
      myOLED.drawImage(Img_HP_1, 0, 16);
    }
    if(movementCounter <=0){
      bool hasMoved = false;
      if(numberX > 1000 && posX < 96){
        posX++;
        hasMoved = true;
      }
      if(numberX < 100 && posX > 32){
        posX--;
        hasMoved = true;
      }
      if(numberY > 1000 && posY < 56){
        posY++;
        hasMoved = true;
      }
      if(numberY < 100 && posY > 24){
        posY--;
        hasMoved = true;
      }
      if(hasMoved){
        movementCounter = 150;
      }
    }
    else{
      movementCounter--;
    }
    
    if((enemyPosX < posX + 6 && enemyPosX > posX - 6) && (enemyPosY < posY + 6 && enemyPosY > posY - 6)){
      tone(13, 128);
      hp--;
    }
    myOLED.drawCircle(posX, posY, 4, false, true);
    myOLED.drawCircle(posX, posY, 2, true, true);
    noTone(13);
    myOLED.clrScr();
  } else {
    myOLED.drawImage(Img_HP_0, 0, 16);
  }
  if(digitalRead(SW_pin) == 0){
    hp = 3;
  }
}
```

I hope it helps! and also hope you can go through my bad english... sorry about that...